# while trying to use xlsxwriter worksheet.data_validation() I get the error message: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'data_validation'

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to edit an excel file by writing some values to excel cells with openpyxl, the problem I ran into was that all my drop down lists (data validation) are now gone. so I am trying to set them up again after writing, using worksheet.data_validation() but for some reason, pycharm doesnt recognizes it.

sheet1.data_validation(3,4,{'validate':'list','source':['1','2']})
(sheet1 is a worksheet)

If there is another way to generate an excel drop down list using python I'll be happy to know about it.
I've also tried using openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation  like in this link: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html and it corrupted my file.

Comment: Please provide more details. The code provided looks wrong and is not covered by the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

With Row/Column notation you must specify all four cells in the range: (first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col).
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_data_validation.html